# CSS - Opacity on textarea : text but not border

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea with border attributes :

```
#my_textarea{
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 550px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 28px;
    /* Text style */
    font-family: Times-Italic;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #717171;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: left;
    resize: none;
  }
```

I want the text inside this `textarea` to have opacity. But when I set `opacity: 0.5;` it also affects the border.

How to set `opacity` only on text inside `textarea` and not text + border ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an RGBA text color

```
color: rgba(113,113,113,0.5);
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#my_textarea {
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  /* Text style */
  font-family: Times-Italic;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgba(113, 113, 113, 0.5);
  line-height: 27px;
  text-align: left;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_textarea">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an `RGBA` value for your `color` should fix the problem you have.

Below is an example.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
#my_textarea {
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 550px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  font-family: Times-Italic;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-align: left;
  resize: none;
  color: rgba(113,113,113, 0.5);
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea">Lorum Ipsum</textarea>
```

[Generator](http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding what @Paulie_D said you should set opacity as rgba color for text:

```
#my_textarea{
    rgba(113, 113, 113, 0.5); //instead of #717171
}
```

Also there is a nice hex-> rgba color [converter](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to complement the other answers, for IE8 (if required - as RGBA is not supported by it) would be to have a wrapper element around the `textarea` and use `opacity` instead of RGBA color:

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
.foo {
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}
#my_textarea {
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 550px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  font-family: Times-Italic;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-align: left;
  resize: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #717171;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <textarea id="my_textarea">Lorum Ipsum</textarea>
</div>
```